# add entries to an array in bash

Tags: linux, bash

In bash I'm trying to create an array and then run through a loop a number of times (determined by the user of the file) and then add a choice to that array the predetermined number of times.  This is trade data, so for example, I choose 2 for factors.  Then the program asks me to input the factor I want, and I put in open (open price of the day), then bid is added to the array arr and the question is asked again.  Then I put in close (close price of the day) then close is added to the array, and in the end the 
arr = open close like that.  But I run the code and the question: `"How many factors would you like to check total: "` simply runs over and over again and I never leave the loop and it never appears that the inputs are being put into the array.  Any help as to my mistake here is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
   factor=""
    total=0
    declare -a arr


read -p "How many factors would you like to check total: " -e -i "$total" total

for (( x=1; x=total; x++ ))
do
        read -p "Enter factor from list: " -e -i "$factor" factor       
        arr+=(${arr[@]} "$factor")
done

echo ${arr[@]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it correct on array append. Just remember that `+=` operator doesn't need full reference to array again on RHS. e.g. just

```
arr+=($factor)
```

Would be suffice to append `$factor` at the end of array variable `arr`.

Modify your script a little bit like this:

```
factor=""
total=0
declare -a arr

read -p "How many factors would you like to check total: " -e -i "$total" total

for (( x=1; x<=total; x++ ))
do
   read -p "Enter factor from list: " -e -i "$factor" factor       
   arr+=($factor)
done

echo ${arr[@]}
```

Comment: Glad to know, pls consider accepting the answer whenever you can.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo

```
for (( x=1; x=total; x++ ))
```

should be

```
for (( x=1; x==total; x++ ))
```

In the first one you are assigning total to x which is always true. In the second one you are checking for equality.